# Amchart4 with OS devices

Tags: iphone, amcharts4

I am using Amchart4 with our ASP.net web application to create a simple dashboard, am facing a problem with all Apple devices my dashboard does not appear on any IOS device even if am using chrome on iPhone

Comment: Hi Ibra, this post would be much more actionable if posed as a question, as well as including additional details including what debugging steps you've taken.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.